# ggplot2 plotting with evaluated values as a result

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

How could I obtain the mean with confidence intervals not only with a graphical plot, but also with numerical data as a result of the following expression?

```
m <- melt(x, id="time")
k <- ggplot(m, aes(x=time, y=value)) +
     stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_boot", geom="smooth")
k
```

I've tried to examine the contents of k, but I've only found my initial data, and not the final results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the function you have used in `stat_summary`:

```
tapply(m$value, m$time, mean_cl_boot)
```

The function `tapply` is used to apply a function to subsets of data. Here, the data is `m$value`. The subsets are defined by `m$time`. The function `mean_cl_boot` is applied to all subsets of the data separately.

Comment: Wow... Is there a manual where I could get some more informations about it?

Comment: @jackb I added an explanation. You can also have a look at `?tapply`?

Comment: E.g. if I want to extract the density functions that are plotted [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_density.html) in the third picture counting from the bottom (of the page), I don't think that the same solution could be used, since I have no `fun.data` function here to call. 

I'm asking this question in order to not replicate in the future similar questions on stackoverflow... thanks again!

Comment: @jackb You can use the function `density`.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the pattern (since ggplot2 should extend some preexisting functions)